# How to get VueJS transitioning Divs beside eachother?

Tags: vue.js, animate.css

When using Vue transitions with a slide left/right animation, how can I get the Divs beside eachother?

Take a look at this pen;
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jeBBaB

HTML

```
<div class="heading">
  <h1>Transition demo</h1>
  <h4>Why this no work?</h4>
</div>

<div class="container" id="app">

    <transition :enter-active-class="enterAnimation" :leave-active-class="leaveAnimation" mode="">

      <div key="one" v-if="currentStep == 1">
        This is Step One
      <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="currentStep = 2; previousStep=1">Next</button>
      </div>

        <div key="two" v-else>
        This is Step Two
      <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="currentStep = 1; previousStep=2">Back</button>
      </div>

  </transition>

</div>
```

CSS

```
$purple: #5c4084;

body {
  background-color: $purple;
  padding: 50px;
}
.container {
  padding: 40px 80px 15px 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  max-width: 800px;
}
.heading {
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: #fff;
  }
  h4 {
    color: lighten(#5c3d86,30%);
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 35px 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
.btn{
  outline: none !important;
}
.btn.btn-primary {
  background-color: $purple;
  border-color: $purple;
  outline: none;
  &:hover {
    background-color: darken($purple, 10%);
    border-color: darken($purple, 10%);
  }
  &:active, &:focus {
    background-color: lighten($purple, 5%);
    border-color: lighten($purple, 5%);
  }
  & .fa {
    padding-right: 4px;
  }
}
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentStep: 1,
    previousStep: 0
  },
  computed:{
      enterAnimation() {
        if (this.currentStep < this.previousStep) {
          return "animated slower fadeInLeft";
        } else {
          return "animated slower fadeInRight";
        }
      },
      leaveAnimation() {
        if (this.currentStep > this.previousStep) {
          return "animated slower fadeOutLeft";
        } else {
          return "animated slower fadeOutRight";
        }
      }
  }
});
```

When using no mode, the "entering" div appears on the line below the "leaving" div until then end, then it pops upwards.

I can use mode="out-in" but then there's a noticable gap between the Divs. I'd like to just have one sliding in, right next to the one sliding out. Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of absolute positioning on the div elements, you need to adjust your css a bit though.

But as a starting point, change your .container rules to this (adding position: relative;):

```
.container {
padding: 40px 80px 15px 80px;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 8px;
max-width: 800px;
position:relative;
}
```

and add this as a new rule below it:

```
.container div {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
```

**The flexbox way:**

Change your container rules to this:

```
.container {
padding: 40px 80px 15px 80px;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 8px;
max-width: 800px;
display:flex;
}
```

After this you can use a css translate rule to position the content. You can see a working example here:

[Vue transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes)

Comment: Thanks, the helps, although the problem with that is if the content of Step2 is a lot 'long' it hangs out the bottom of the container :( https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KGWGbr

Comment: Alright, another alternative would be to do it with flexbox, I'll update my answer with something to get you started